# Accessing Vertica Database via a shareable file DSN on Excel

Tags: odbc

I am trying to connect to a Vertica database (*Vertica driver=7.02.03*) on our server. I have created a .dsn file using the FILE DSN tab on ODBC Data Source Administration (*64 bit*).  However, when I want to connect to the database via Excel(*16.0.12527 64-bit*), my file DSN does not show up on the 'From ODBC' list in Excel. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try 32-Bit? Do you have a 32-Bit or 64-Bit driver for Vertica? Welcome to DBA.SE.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. The platform is for both 32/64 bit. I managed to solve the problem. Thank you for your reply.